# How can I make button go right, fix middle section and make everything resizible

Tags: html, css

I have a 3 sections in my html

1. textarea
2. lable and below 2 buttons
3. road button

How can I make everything resizible and have seconds section fixed so it doesn't resize (label and below 2 buttons) and have 3 button Road go on the right and doesn't move, it should be fixed.

So in the nutshell, textarea should be resizible and seconds section and button the right should be fixed.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main_section" class="container">
            <div class="cstm-item d-flex"> 
                <div class="">
                    <textarea name=""></textarea> 
                </div>
                <div  class="h-100 text-center">
                    <span>LEFT RIGHT</span>                 
                    <div>
                        <button><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
                        <button><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>          
            </div>
            <div>
                <button><i class="fa fa-road"></i></button>
            </div>      
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: share some codes with us.

Comment: @AbhilekhGautam sorry had some issues with editor to inject code..here it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution would work. Let me know if there is anything wrong in UI alignment.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    </head>
    <style>
        .solution {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
        }
        .solution > div {
            padding: 0 10px;
        }
        .solution > div:first-of-type {
            flex-grow: 1;
        }
        textarea {
            width: 100%;
        }
        
    </style>
    <body>
        <div id="main_section" class="container">
            <div class="solution">
                <div>
                    <textarea class="item-text-area" name=""></textarea> 
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span>LEFT RIGHT</span>                 
                    <div>
                        <button><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
                        <button><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>       
                <div>
                    <button><i class="fa fa-road"></i></button>
                </div>       
            </div>  
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can we put second section (label and 2 buttons plus minus) on the right in the line where is textarea. Then also far right can we put button Road. So everything is in 1 line.

Comment: If this fixed your problem, it would be great if you can accept this solution so that I can get point 15 ;)